# SharePoint Date wrong in Power Bi

Tags: date-time, timezone, powerbi

I have a list in sharepoint where in create items with date and time amongst other data.

Eg. I have one where I entered the date 14-06-2019 05:00:00

Now when I pull this into Power Bi the date is 14-06-2019 12:00:00

I have been looking into time zones, but can't quite figure out how to change it.

I don't have admin rights to the SharePoint site, so I can't do anything about the time zone there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the described solution. Now, my SharePoint date columns are showing correct in PowerBi. However, I have encountered another issue related to these dates. When I upload my .pbix file to PowerBi Online (to schedule daily updates), then if I export the summarized data to Excel from the PowerBi report it again shows the wrong dates. If I export it from PowerBi desktop, the dates are correct. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance, Kristine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI is pulling the data as UTC.

[image]

You can confirm this if you go to 'Edit Query' in your Power BI file and change the type of the date column to Date/Time/Timezone, which will show you the timezone offset settings for the date as well.

[image]

Now, you can duplicate this 'Date/Time/Timezone' column to create a new one and then use same 'Change Type' option to select the last option 'Using Locale', which would open the form to select your 'Locale' and then transform the date according to that Locale.

[image]

[image]

After applying the changes, 'Modified Date' is showing value in my current Locale:

[image]